# Manually Implement the client side of OAuth2's Auth Code Flow in .Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-3.1

### Backstory

Due to limitations on what Swagger supports and what my system needs, I find myself needing to get an access token without the assistance of my actual application.  I am trying to do it in an IOperationFilter.

### Question Details

The steps, as I see them, are:

1. Make a call to the IDP with the Callback URL (and PKCE Code Challenge).
2. The Browser is redirected to the IDP's login page and the user logs in.
3. The Browser is redirected to the callback url with the Auth Code in the URL.
4. Make a call to the IDP with the Auth Code and PKCE Code Verifier to get the Access Token.

I can get the URL needed to call the IDP (with the PKCE Code Challenge).  But I am unsure how to make the redirect to IDP login happen or catch the Callback URL to get the Auth Code Out.  I tried `HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Redirect` but it had no effect.

I am also not sure how to grab the call with the AuthCode in it.  I could startup my own host using `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureWebHostDefaults`, but it seems like I should not need to host a separate service inside my existing service.

### Question

**How from code run when the page is initially loaded, how can I redirect the browser to the IDP, and then catch the redirect from there to the page with the Auth Code in the URL?**

Comment: Are you sure swagger doesn't support the flow? I'm using a similar setup and have been able to configuration the authorization just fine (albeit after a lot of guess work)

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 - It supports it to a point. But after it gets the token, I need to send both the Access Token (as Bearer) and the ID token(as a normal header). I cannot find a way to make it send both. (I have to choose one or the other.). My system needs both.

Comment: I don't know how to accomplish that, but almost everything is configurable via built in options and custom filters. You might have better luck asking over on the swagger repos